# Multiple database & multiple framework in same project

Tags: node.js, mongodb, postgresql, django-rest-framework, microservices

I have project idea where have N number module, some module require highly relational structure and some module have highly nested data structure. So I want to use django rest & nodejs for backend; postgresql & mongodb for database. Is it possible? Or another idea to solve this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: Sure it is. It makes the project complex, difficult to maintain and easy to break, but it’s possible. I would try to make it simpler

Comment: @FrankHeikens thanks for your reply, can you give me some idea? My team has nodejs & django developers, I want to utilize them fully.